# Is X always in any open neighborhood system for the topological space X, t?

Tags: general-topology

I have just been recently introduced to the concept of open neighborhood systems, but the fact that X is in any open neighborhood system $N_x$ in X, $t$ is not self-evident to me. Is this always true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. By definition any topology on $X$ includes the set $X$ itself, so $X$ is an open nbhd of every point of $X$.